# Hold time in session and compare the difference

Tags: php, session, session-variables, microtime

I have a code that I want to check for time differences. This code below will check the the time start and time end then it will display the total time taken.

When I first load the page, the time will initialize in session. After that I will wait for a few **seconds** and then change the `$test` variable to `1`. The `if` will then executed and display `Total time taken`.  Then the session will be destroyed and reset everything.

However the code does not works. Time in microseconds to reflect the waited seconds is not shown??

```
<?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['time_start'])){
        $_SESSION['time_start']=microtime(true);
        }

$test ='';

if (!empty($test)){

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $display = $time_end - $_SESSION['time_start'];

    echo "Total time taken: $display";
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

Comment: How are you waiting and changing the variable, in the php script itself? If it is in another request, `$test` will not exist and your original script will have finished running. And you need `session_start()` at the top of each script.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot the `session_start()`. It works now.

Comment: @sg552 why are you storing `microtime` in the `$_SESSION` superglobal?  I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing this (and manually changing & refreshing the script after you've modified the $test variable):

```
$test ='';

if (!empty($test)){
```

Try this script instead:

```
session_start();
$current_time = microtime(true);

if (isset($_SESSION['time_start']) && !empty($_SESSION['time_start']))
{
    $time_end = $current_time;
    $display = $time_end - $_SESSION['time_start'];

    echo "Total time taken: $display";
    $_SESSION['time_start'] = '';
    session_destroy();
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['time_start'] = $current_time;
    echo "Initial time variable set, press refresh.";
}
```

I think the main issue is that you missed calling 'session_start()' at the top of the script.

What will happen with the above script is the 'else' part will run first as the 'time_start' part of the session isn't initially set, and/or is empty. This will set the data into the session. The next page load the if statement should run and it will display the time between refreshes.